# Replace a specific character only between parenthesis

Tags: r, regex, gsub

Lest's say I have a string:

```
test <- "(pop+corn)-bread+salt"
```

I want to replace the plus sign that is only between parenthesis by '|', so I get:

```
"(pop|corn)-bread+salt"
```

I tried:

```
gsub("([+])","\\|",test)
```

But it replaces all the plus signs of the string (obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try

```
sub("(\\([^+]+)\\+","\\1|", test)
#[1] "(pop|corn)-bread+salt"
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace all `+` symbols that are inside parentheses (if there may be 1 *or more*), you can use any of the following solutions:

```
gsub("\\+(?=[^()]*\\))", "|", x, perl=TRUE)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IBJHkB/2). Here, the `+` is only matched when it is followed with any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` (with `[^()]*`) and then a `)`. *It is only good if the input is well-formed and there is no nested parentheses* as it does not check if there was a starting `(`.

```
gsub("(?:\\G(?!^)|\\()[^()]*?\\K\\+", "|", x, perl=TRUE)
```

This is a safer solution since it starts matching `+` only if there was a starting `(`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IBJHkB/3). In this pattern, `(?:\G(?!^)|\()` matches the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) or (`|`) a `(`, then `[^()]*?` matches any 0+ chars other than `(` and `)` chars, and then `\K` discards all the matched text and `\+` matches a `+` that will be consumed and replaced. It still does not handle nested parentheses.

Also, see an [online R demo for the above two solutions](https://ideone.com/aZkOfB).

```
library(gsubfn)
s <- "(pop(+corn)+unicorn)-bread+salt+malt"
gsubfn("\\((?:[^()]++|(?R))*\\)", ~ gsub("+", "|", m, fixed=TRUE), s, perl=TRUE, backref=0)
## => [1] "(pop(|corn)|unicorn)-bread+salt+malt"
```

This solves the problem of matching nested parentheses, but requires the `gsubfn` package. See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IBJHkB/4/). See [this regex description here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html#balanced).

Note that in case you do not have to match nested parentheses, you may use `"\\([^()]*\\)"` regex with the `gsubfn` code above. `\([^()]*\)` regex matches `(`, then any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` (replace with `[^)]*` to match `)`) and then a `)`.

Comment: This would also work: `gsubfn("\\(.*?\\)", ~ chartr("+", "|", x), test)` where `"\\("` is an open parenthesis without special meaning and `.*?\\)` is the shortest string of any characters until a close parenthesis.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck That does not handle nested parentheses, and I was interested to share at least one nested parentheses handling solution. Besides, `"\\([^)]*\\)"` (that will match `(abc)def)` in `(abc)def)`) or `"\\([^()]*\\)"` (same as `"\\(.*?\\)"`, will match `(abc)` in `(abc)def)`) will be more efficient than a lazy dot.

Comment: It does not handle nested parentheses but it is shorter and nested parentheses does not seem part of the problem.  If nested parentheses were required one can retain a simple regex by using a proto object with gsubfn to count them.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck See [**this demo**](https://regex101.com/r/IBJHkB/4/). Strings between balanced parentheses are matched.