# How do I split a complex string using regex or string manipulation?

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I have a list of ingredients as follows:

```
Ingredients <- "Starch (Corn | Potato | Wheat) | Vegetables (27%) [Pea (23%) (Flakes | Pieces) | Carrot Pieces | Onion Powder | Spinach Powder] | Croutons (10%) (Wheat Flour | Vegetable Oil | Salt | Yeast) | Maltodextrin | Natural Flavours (Contain Milk and Soybeans) | Creamer [Contains Milk | Mineral Salts (339 or 340 | 450 or 451)] | Salt | Mineral Salt (Potassium Chloride) | Sugar | Flavour Enhancer (621) | Vegetable Oil | Bacon Powder (0.5%) | Parsley | Natural Colour (Turmeric) | Burnt Sugar | Food Acid (Lactic) | Pepper Extract"
```

I want to separate them into values in a dataframe under variable `ingredients`.

But I am having trouble writing the code because the separator `|` is used in various ways in the list. So I want to split on `|` where it's not contained within brackets `()` or square brackets `[]`. And don't really know how to approach this.

That is, we'd end up with an ingredient value of `Starch (Corn | Potato | Wheat)` and another of `Vegetables (27%) [Pea (23%) (Flakes | Pieces) | Carrot Pieces | Onion Powder | Spinach Powder]` and another which is just `Salt` (plus other ingredients, but those first two are the trickier cases to me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Regex modified from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48856131/16647496).

The idea is to substitute the `|` character in between parentheses (`()` and `[]`) to something else (`@` in my example) first. The remaining `|` character should be the real separator of your strings. Then use `strsplit` to split on `|` and substitute the `@` symbol back to `|`. Finally, `trims()` to remove unwanted white spaces at the ends of each string.

```
library(dplyr)

strsplit(gsub("\\|(?=[^()]*\\))", "@", Ingredients, perl=TRUE) %>% 
           gsub("\\|(?=[^\\[\\]]*\\])", "@", ., perl=TRUE), "\\|") %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  gsub("@", "\\|", .) %>% 
  trimws()

 [1] "Starch (Corn | Potato | Wheat)"                                                                
 [2] "Vegetables (27%) [Pea (23%) (Flakes | Pieces) | Carrot Pieces | Onion Powder | Spinach Powder]"
 [3] "Croutons (10%) (Wheat Flour | Vegetable Oil | Salt | Yeast)"                                   
 [4] "Maltodextrin"                                                                                  
 [5] "Natural Flavours (Contain Milk and Soybeans)"                                                  
 [6] "Creamer [Contains Milk | Mineral Salts (339 or 340 | 450 or 451)]"                             
 [7] "Salt"                                                                                          
 [8] "Mineral Salt (Potassium Chloride)"                                                             
 [9] "Sugar"                                                                                         
[10] "Flavour Enhancer (621)"                                                                        
[11] "Vegetable Oil"                                                                                 
[12] "Bacon Powder (0.5%)"                                                                           
[13] "Parsley"                                                                                       
[14] "Natural Colour (Turmeric)"                                                                     
[15] "Burnt Sugar"                                                                                   
[16] "Food Acid (Lactic)"                                                                            
[17] "Pepper Extract"
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use a recursive regex:

```
pat <- r"(([^\[\]|]*[\[(](?:[^\[)(\]]*(?1)?)+[\])])| ([^|]+))"
regmatches(Ingredients, gregexpr(pat, Ingredients, perl = TRUE))

[[1]]
 [1] "Starch (Corn | Potato | Wheat)"                                                                 
 [2] " Vegetables (27%) [Pea (23%) (Flakes | Pieces) | Carrot Pieces | Onion Powder | Spinach Powder]"
 [3] " Croutons (10%) (Wheat Flour | Vegetable Oil | Salt | Yeast)"                                   
 [4] " Maltodextrin "                                                                                 
 [5] " Natural Flavours (Contain Milk and Soybeans)"                                                  
 [6] " Creamer [Contains Milk | Mineral Salts (339 or 340 | 450 or 451)]"                             
 [7] " Salt "                                                                                         
 [8] " Mineral Salt (Potassium Chloride)"                                                             
 [9] " Sugar "                                                                                        
[10] " Flavour Enhancer (621)"                                                                        
[11] " Vegetable Oil "                                                                                
[12] " Bacon Powder (0.5%)"                                                                           
[13] " Parsley "                                                                                      
[14] " Natural Colour (Turmeric)"                                                                     
[15] " Burnt Sugar "                                                                                  
[16] " Food Acid (Lactic)"                                                                            
[17] " Pepper Extract"
```

Comment: Nice use of the raw string. +1